# Rxjava2: Usage of Single & CompositeDisposable

Tags: android, rx-java2

Background:

I'm trying to load an image with Glide and rxjava2 (to make use of background thread).

I'm still confused how each component of rxjava2 api works.

So below are my questions.

Q1: Is it impossible to `add` `Single` to `CompositeDisposable`?

Whenever I try to add `Single` into `CompositeDisposable`, Android Studio warns me that there is type mismatch.

However if I call `toObservable()` before `subscribeOn`, error message goes away.

Q2: Correct my usage of `rxjava2` with `Glide` if there are some problems.

```
   private void loadImages(final String imageUri) {
            Single<GlideRequest<Drawable>> glideSingle = Single.fromCallable(
                    new Callable<GlideRequest<Drawable>>() {
                        @Override
                        public GlideRequest<Drawable> call() {
                            return GlideApp.with(MainActivity.this).load(imageUri);
                        }
                    }
            );

            // mSubscription is just new CompositeDisposable()
            mSubscription.add(
                glideSingle
                        .toObservable() // I have to call this to suppress error message
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeWith(
                                new DisposableObserver<GlideRequest<Drawable>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onNext(GlideRequest<Drawable> drawableGlideRequest) {
                                        RequestOptions backgroundTransformOptions = new RequestOptions()
                                                .transforms(
                                                        new CenterCrop(),
                                                        new BlurTransformation(60),
                                                        new ColorFilterTransformation(
                                                                ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorBackgroundOverlay))
                                                );

                                        drawableGlideRequest
                                                .into(mAlbumArt);

                                        drawableGlideRequest
                                                .apply(backgroundTransformOptions)
                                                .into(mMainBackground);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete() {

                                    }
                                }
                        )
            );
        }
```

Comment: You have a flow with `Single` thus you need its consumer type: `SingleObserver` of which the [JavaDocs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html) clearly gives an example by using `subscribeWith`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather then *subscribeWith* you should be able to use the regular *subscribe* method.

This will return a Disposable, e.g. without lambda support this would look something like this:

```
mSubscription.add(
    glideSingle
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<GlideRequest<Drawable>>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(GlideRequest<Drawable> drawableGlideRequest) throws Exception {

                RequestOptions backgroundTransformOptions = new RequestOptions()
                    .transforms(
                        new CenterCrop(),
                        new BlurTransformation(60),
                        new ColorFilterTransformation(
                            ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorBackgroundOverlay))
                    );

                drawableGlideRequest
                    .into(mAlbumArt);

                drawableGlideRequest
                    .apply(backgroundTransformOptions)
                    .into(mMainBackground);

            }
        }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {

            }
        })
);
```